# efficiently load and search a webpage with tons of text

Tags: javascript, css, dom

In order to implement a simple cocktail search on my website, I currently load every record to be searched onto the page and filter them with CSS: https://www.chrisfnicholson.com/drinks.html

It works, it's pretty quick because the text isn't much for each drink, but it seems inefficient to load 500 drinks all at once when only a handful are visible on the screen at a time.

What I'd like is to find a way to improve this so the site downloads quickly, can be interacted with and searched immediately, and isn't held back by having to render such a huge DOM.

Comment: Very useful site :)

Comment: Create a JSON with the cockails and use it locally. Or seek for an existing one, like https://github.com/teijo/iba-cocktails/blob/master/recipes.json

Comment: Once you’ve generated it what do you do with?

Comment: @cfn In case one wants to follow a plain data structure based approach one has to decide to either load all data at once as huge blob which is close to what the OP already does with the HTML/DOM based version, or one follows an API based approach (which also supports ingredient based filtering) similar to what is suggested with the first answer of [NVRM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2494754/nvrm).
In the 1st case one has to build a 2nd structure from the blob which allows ingredient based filtering.
For both cases one has to build DOM fragments from the search result and rerender the DOM.

Comment: @cfn ... in terms of performance I would leave the existing side and its approach untouched/unchanged.

Comment: @Peter That’s what I needed to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer you are looking for, but a demo of a possible alternative.

Use a remote API like https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api.php.

If you are more into front end, this is the easiest.

[Example JSON](https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita)

```js
fetch("https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita")
  .then(v => v.json()).then((function(v){
   
    // console.log(v)
  
    console.log(v["drinks"][0]["strDrink"])
    console.log(v["drinks"][0]["strIngredient1"])
    console.log(v["drinks"][0]["strIngredient2"])
    console.log(v["drinks"][0]["strIngredient3"])
    console.log(v["drinks"][0]["strIngredient4"])
    console.log(v["drinks"][0]["strInstructions"])
  })
)
```

NB: it works from a browser because this API has [CORS enabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)